# How to update or add tracking codes to shopware 6 order via API?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I want to update or add tracking codes to orders in shopware, the same way that it is done in the admin panel via the API.
[Admin panel field to add or update tracking codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRlu2.png)

**First Try**
I first tried copying the payload used by the admin panel
[Payload of the admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCOJ9.png)
I got this error
[error from copied payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ2En.png)
**Second Try**
2. I tried using the patch method from the documentation
[Patch Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy8Do.png)
I got this error
[error in the admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8xfs.png)

> request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET https://(domain)/69d9897fb4db7b7c9c28.worker.js.map"" at /home/schcmjkg/staging/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 135 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for "GET https://(domain)/69d9897fb4db7b7c9c28.worker.js.map" at /home/schcmjkg/staging/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:135)\n[previous exception] [object] (Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for "/69d9897fb4db7b7c9c28.worker.js.map/". at /home/schcmjkg/staging/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/Dumper/CompiledUrlMatcherTrait.php:74)"} []

But the tracking codes were added everytime(not updated), which gave the error i presume.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIIm0.png)
I could add the other images but bascically te-he same order ended up with different tracking codes with same shipping ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll have to fetch the id of the `order_delivery` associated with the order.

```
GET /api/order/{orderId}?associations[deliveries][]&includes[order][]=deliveries&includes[order_delivery][]=id
```

Response example:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "deliveries": [
            {
                "id": "9d1994d328b44f3e941c9484415ec95c",
                "apiAlias": "order_delivery"
            }
        ],
        "apiAlias": "order"
    }
}
```

Take the id from the response and use it to update the `order_delivery` record.

```
PATCH /api/order-delivery/9d1994d328b44f3e941c9484415ec95c
```

Request body:

```json
{
  "trackingCodes": ["foobar"]
}
```